# Visual Basic string equals operator not working

Tags: string, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, comparison, basic

```
If (UsersTableAdapter.FillByUsername(Me.DatabaseDataSet1.users, username) <> 0) Then

    type = DatabaseDataSet1.users.First.UserType

    MsgBox(type)

    If type = "Staff" Then
        MsgBox("You are staff")
    ElseIf type = "Student" Then
        MsgBox("You are student")
    Else
        MsgBox("Something else")
    End If

End If
```

My code first grabs the user's `UserType` from the database. It then compares the values of `type` with `Staff` and `Student`. I added a message box to output `type` and confirmed `type` is being correctly pulled from the database.

**Why isn't the `if` returning `true` in the comparison?**

I have also tried using `.equals()` and `.toString()` functions but still no luck.

Comment: Same case ? "Staff" <> "staff" also check if there are hidden spaces at the end of the type variable (MsgBox(type.Length) should be 5 for "Staff")

Comment: Time to start using an Enum instead of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm with @Steve as to what the most likely problem is. You might want to try using `ToLower()` and `Trim()`.

Note the two cases Steve mentioned (case and hidden spaces) in the following code:

```
    Dim Type = "staff    "

    MsgBox(Type)

    If Type.ToLower().Trim() = "Staff".ToLower() Then
        MsgBox("You are staff")
    ElseIf Type = "Student" Then
        MsgBox("You are student")
    Else
        MsgBox("Something else")
    End If
```

Comment: Thanks, yeh for some reason when writing to the db a bunch of spaces were getting in there!